# how to print statement with join function in between?

Tags: perl, join

I would like to print a statement like this

```
print "$string -> $string1 ( join (",", @array) )\n";
```

but i found that i cannot print the result of join function but the join just print like normal word. For example my $string = a , $string1= b and @array = c d e give me the result like below

```
a -> b (join (",",@array) )
```

The actual result i want is something like this.

```
a -> b (c,d,e)
```

Any solution i can get the result i want?

Answer (score 4):

That is correct, you cannot print like that. Code cannot be executed inside of double quotes.  Instead, join the result of code, for example:

```
print "$str -> $str ( " . join(',', @array) . ")\n";
```

There is a number of other ways to do it, but the main point is that code cannot run inside quotes.

Comment: "_Code cannot be executed inside of double quotes_" -- except, of course, under `".. @{[...]} .."` as in jm666 answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `printf`

```
printf "%s -> $s (%s)\n", $string1, $string2, join(',', @array);
```

Or if you want to store the string in a variable (or return it from a function) use `sprintf`;

```
my $output = sprintf "%s -> $s (%s)\n", $string1, $string2, join(',', @array);
# ... later
print $output;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply separate the print to multiple statements. But if you want do it in one step, could use:

```
print "$string -> $string1 ( @{[ join(',',@arr) ]} )\n";
```

Code inside an double quoted string can be executed using the [baby-cart operator](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod), `@{[ ... ]}`. Of course, this isn't recommented practice - because hard to read - use one of the other answers. :)